# Mask a displacement?

Tags: shaders, displacement, masking

[image]Blender File:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OSVhKAGRYp-l9eqZiaR-o_XeKvsDtmE-/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Hello, I'm trying to only have the tan camo areas displace this texture. I tried plugging the mask I already created to mask out the tan areas, and then plug that into a mix rgb factor, connected to the displacement, but that made the displacement do something crazy.  Refer to the file for more clarity! Thanks in advance!! Also, any way to increase displace quality, other than subdividing?

Almost there, now have height in areas I want, but I don't know how to connect to the height node

Comment: Use the camo mask for the height input

Comment: @AllenSimpson Just uploaded two images of me trying that. Did I do it wrong?

Comment: Oh ok, yeah the image texture should be plugged into Height as usual, but use this mask you've generated as the Scale input.  You might have to adjust white color down on the color ramp or use a math -> divide node to further control the scale

Comment: @AllenSimpson That did it! A color ramp controlling the scale was the trick. Thank you!!